# Reflection of a light object in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, shaders, light, reflection

i'm trying to recreate the same lightning condition from that shot (see screenshot), but i'm having troubles to give a little reflection to the light object (ceiling).

Any tips on how to achieve this result?

Thank you!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can create reflective materials by lowering the *Roughness* and increasing the *Metallic* properties.
[image]